# Can't load Private Key using OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I try to load my Private Key using this.

```
openssl rsa -text -in pk.key -inform DER
```

but I got this error

```
unable to load Private Key
64964:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long:crypto\asn1\asn1_lib.c:101:
```

how can I fix that?

Comment: Look at your file and/or the procedure that created it to determine what is actually in it. If it actually is a privatekey but in some other form, the fix depends on what that other form is. If you can't figure it out, and add to your Q the first line or two of a hexdump (i.e. first 16-32 bytes), we can probably guess. If it actually is not a privatekey, whether there is a fix depends on what you want or need to do, which you didn't give any hint of.

Comment: Open the key file in an editor. If you see hex data the format is `PEM` not `DER`.